# Full Logout with openid.php provider

Tags: php, session, cookies, openid

I have a PHP appliation that uses the LightOpenID (openid.php) provider.  The logins are working fine but the logouts are not.  After logging out you can immediately choose the option to log back in and it signs you in without issue.  This poses a security issue and is not how I want the app to behave.  After logging out, I need to ensure that the user is challenged (for at least their password) again.  For my logout page I have:

```
    <?php // RAY_EE_logout.php
session_start();

// CLEAR THE INFORMATION FROM THE $_SESSION ARRAY
$_SESSION = array();

// IF THE SESSION IS KEPT IN COOKIE, FORCE SESSION COOKIE TO EXPIRE


if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
{
   $cookie_expires  = time() - date('Z') - 3600;
   setcookie(session_name(), '', $cookie_expires, '/');
}



// TELL PHP TO ELIMINATE THE SESSION
session_destroy();

// REDIRECT TO THE HOME PAGE AFTER A FULL LOGOUT THROUGH GOOGLE
header("Location: https://accounts.google.com/Logout");
//exit;
?>
```

I just recently added the header to be https://accounts.google.com/Logout (instead of redirecting back to my home page).  This seems to do the trick but I want the users to end up on my home page after logging out and not the Google page.  I tried to use https://accounts.google.com/Logout?continue=http://www.mysite.com but Google doesn't seem to accept that and throws an error.

The login page is basically:

```
    <?php
require 'openid.php';
try {
    # Change 'localhost' to your domain name.
    $openid = new LightOpenID('www.mydomain.com');


    if(!$openid->mode) 
    {
        if(isset($_GET['login'])) 
        {
            $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
            $openid->required = array('contact/email'); // grab the users email as well (google only)
            header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
        }
    } elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
        echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
    } else {


        session_start();
        $_SESSION['auth'] = 'yes';
        $returnVariables = $openid->getAttributes();
    $_SESSION['emailAddress'] = $returnVariables['contact/email'];

}
}

?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: After logout it will go for home page,is it your question ?

Comment: Yes after a full logout I need to redirect back to my home page.

Comment: can you give your login page code?

Comment: In your login page,where is your logout link ?Do you have given logout link in logout page?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code with a simple code here your logout code is working fine.I thing there some problem in your link.In `logout.php` page why you linked again `logout.php`?`logout.php` is it your home page? Here the code that I have tried.

home.php code

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

login.php code

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    if($name='abc' && $password='123')
    {
        echo 'you are login!';
        echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
    }
    else
    die("password not match!!");
?>
```

logout.php code

```
 <?php // RAY_EE_logout.php
session_start();

// CLEAR THE INFORMATION FROM THE $_SESSION ARRAY
$_SESSION = array();

// IF THE SESSION IS KEPT IN COOKIE, FORCE SESSION COOKIE TO EXPIRE


if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
{
   $cookie_expires  = time() - date('Z') - 3600;
   setcookie(session_name(), '', $cookie_expires, '/');
}



// TELL PHP TO ELIMINATE THE SESSION
session_destroy();

// REDIRECT TO THE HOME PAGE AFTER A FULL LOGOUT THROUGH GOOGLE
require('home.php');
//exit;
?>
```

Here the output :

[image]

[image]

After click on logout,go for home.php

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this doesn't work.  I get the same results with "require" as I do with "header" going directly to my home page.  Subsequent logins go right through and the user is not challenged.

Comment: I don't get any errors.  It just logs me back in as the same user when I click the login button.  Never challenged for credentials.

Comment: Your example here doesn't make use of the OpenID provider with Google authentication so it is different.  Standard forms-based authentication works as expected for me as well.